# How can I prevent users from updating records in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using Python and sqlite3 to create and add records to a table in a database. Currently I can add, delete and update a record.

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_filename = "...."
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_filename)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test_table(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Date TEXT, Time TEXT)""")
conn.commit()
```

My aim is after I update a record to somehow prevent this specific record from being updated and/or deleted.

Comment: Who are the users? Do they access to the sqlite file? Can they modify your Python code?

Comment: Have those users access to the database file?

Comment: The database is part of a PyQt application. They won't be able to modify my Python code but the database file will be stored on their computer.

Comment: You will have to handle user permissions in your app, and if possible restrict access to the DB file using filesystem permissions (usually you create a user group associated with your app and the app using setgid to be executed with the rights of this group).